# How to count text in a list separated with commas across sheets?

Tags: if-statement, text, sum, find

Ok guys, I'm pretty basic here, so dum it down for me please!
Can you sum the total times text shows up in a list? I have a list of initials that are in two columns in two sheets actually, like this:

Sheet 2
Column E - Column F

OA, GK, EF ......         - PZ

...

Sheet 3

Column E     - Column F

GK, IN, PZ.....    -  OA

...

and I want to tally the number of times each initial shows up for each person in their row in a master sheet 1?

I tried this & I used CNTRL + SHFT + ENTER, but the formula has some flaw:
=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(FIND("OA",'SHEET2!E:F))))+SUM(IF(ISTEXT(FIND("OA",'SHEET3!E:F))))

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I figured it out...I guess I have to use COUNTIF instead of SUMIF, and I don't have to do all the fancy FINd or SEARCH stuff, I can just surround the criteria in stars!!

So, this worked:
=COUNTIF('Sheet2!E:F,"*OA*")+COUNTIF('SHEET3!E:F,"*OA*")

Comment: weird, it's not copying over my stars, they must stand for ITALICIZE or something, but I was putting an asterisk * on either side of OA so that it would allow other text (other initials & the commas) to be on either side of the one I want.